# Azure architecture design for image platform

Tags: azure, architecture, azure-functions, azure-cloud-services

I want to build a image sharing platform for customers to use. This platform will take an image provided by a user, create copies of it at multiple resolutions, and store them ready to be shared or downloaded. How to achieve this using azure in a cost effective ways

Im thinking to use Azure functions(for the api calls) storage blobs , event grid and cosmos db for the same.

Answer (score 0):

To keep the costs low keep it simple:

- Store data in Blob storage. Price varies based on redundancy, speed of access and location
- Azure functions for processing images, consumption plan gives 1M free requests per month
- Azure app service to host web site for uploading images, there is a free tier